# How I can detect memory leaks of C++ application in Linux (Ubuntu OS)?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, memory-leaks

How I can detect memory leaks of C++ application in Linux (Ubuntu OS) ? What is the program you can advise me for this goal ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check out [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it should be in the Ubuntu repository. it can give you detailed information about memory usage in C++ programs. Kind of like a debugger for memory usage.

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck <your_app> <your_apps_params>
```

Comment: One could also add --leak-check=yes

Answer (score 2):

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

also may look [ccmalloc](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/ccmalloc/), [NJAMD](http://fscked.org/projects/njamd), [mpatrol](http://mpatrol.sourceforge.net/), YAMD, [LeakTracer](http://www.andreasen.org/LeakTracer/)

Answer (score 2):

If open source software isn't mandatory you could also check out [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/)